# Select data list from multiple tables

Tags: mysql, sql

Item1 Table:

```
----------------------------------
id  |  name   | price | product_id           
----------------------------------
1   | Laptop  | 50   |  20
2   | PC      | 150  |  10
3   | Notebook| 125  |  25
```

Item2 Table:

```
 ----------------------------------
id  |  name   | price | product_id           
----------------------------------
1   | Mobile  | 50   |  20
2   | Landline| 150  |  10
3   | Pager   | 125  |  25
```

Item3 Table:

```
 ----------------------------------
id  |  name   | price | product_id           
----------------------------------
1   | Canon   | 250   |  20
2   | Nikon   | 150   |  10
3   | Sony    | 325   |  25
```

Master Table:

```
------------------------------------------------------------------
product_id   | quantity     | manufacturer   | shipment | item
------------------------------------------------------------------
20           | 150          |     China      | Delivery | item1  
20           | 200          |     India      | Delivery | item2
20           | 300          |     USA        | Pickup   | item3 
15           | 200          |     USA        | Pickup   | Item2
```

I would like to get the item details from all 3 item tables in order (item1, item2, item3) and the product details for the items from the master table based on the product id (eg: where product id = 20) like the result below:

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
item       | name       | price    | quantity   | manufacturer | shipment 
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
item1      | Laptop     | 50       | 150        | China        | Delivery      
item2      | Mobile     | 50       | 200        | India        | Delivery      
item3      | Canon      | 250      | 300        | USA          | Pickup
```

Thank you very much for the help!

Comment: How do you distinguish which table each row refers to?

Comment: @GordonLinoff it is distinguished by the item column in the master table (item1 refers to Item 1 table, item2 refers to Item 2 table, and so on). Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a `union` can achieve the desired result?

```
SELECT m.item, i.name, i.price, m.quantity, m.manufacturer, m.shipment
FROM Master m
INNER JOIN Item1 i ON i.product_id = m.product_id
WHERE m.item = 'item1'
AND m.product_id = 20

UNION

SELECT m.item, i.name, i.price, m.quantity, m.manufacturer, m.shipment
FROM Master m
INNER JOIN Item2 i ON i.product_id = m.product_id
WHERE m.item = 'item2'
AND m.product_id = 20

UNION 

SELECT m.item, i.name, i.price, m.quantity, m.manufacturer, m.shipment
FROM Master m
INNER JOIN Item3 i ON i.product_id = m.product_id
WHERE m.item = 'item3'
AND m.product_id = 20
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a series of `left join`s:

```
SELECT m.item,
       COALESCE(i1.name, i2.name, i3.name) as name,
       COALESCE(i1.price, i2.price, i3.price) as price,
       m.quantity, m.manufacturer, m.shipment
FROM Master m LEFT JOIN
     Item1 i1
     ON i1.product_id = m.product_id AND
        m.item = 'item1' LEFT JOIN
     Item1 i2
     ON i2.product_id = m.product_id AND
        m.item = 'item2' LEFT JOIN
     Item1 i1
     ON i3.product_id = m.product_id AND
        m.item = 'item3'
WHERE m.product_id = 20;
```

However, I would suggest that you union them together:

```
SELECT m.item,
       COALESCE(i1.name, i2.name, i3.name) as name,
       COALESCE(i1.price, i2.price, i3.price) as price,
       m.quantity, m.manufacturer, m.shipment
FROM Master m LEFT JOIN
     ((SELECT 'item1' as item, i1.*
       FROM Item1 i1
      ) UNION ALL
      (SELECT 'item2' as item, i2.*
       FROM Item1 i2
      ) UNION ALL
      (SELECT 'item3' as item, i3.*
       FROM Item1 i3
      )
     ) i
     ON i.product_id = m.product_id AND
        i.item = m.item
WHERE m.product_id = 20;
```

I would suggest that you store the "items" all in one table, to facilitate such queries.